# Enqueue more than two CSS styles in a child theme functions.php

Tags: child-theme

I've just started to use WordPress and learned about the child-theme feature.
So it's my first time doing this and I ran into some problems.

When I try to preview the child-theme, the **formatting** of the whole site is **messed up**.

Something tells me it's coming from my `functions.php` since I've only enqueued one `style.css` when I have three.

The other two CSS files only have a few lines of code. I can put them on the `style.css` but I don't want to modify the original file that's why I'm using a child-theme feature.
I'm also here to learn more about this stuff for future reference :)

Here's the contents of my `functions.php`

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_enqueue_styles' );
function theme_enqueue_styles() {
wp_enqueue_style( 'parent-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );
```

Please enlighten me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Child theme templates starts working before Parent theme, so if any similar template files (similar to parent theme) exists it tries to override the parent theme's template - that's the core thing about child theme.

The right way to enqueue new stylesheet in Child theme to **make it THE Child Theme** is the following:

```
<?php
function theme_enqueue_styles() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'parent-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_enqueue_styles' );
```

With that in the `functions.php` and a `style.css` with [proper Child Theme formatted comments](http://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes#How_to_Create_a_Child_Theme) you will get a complete new theme based on its parent. And you are done. :)

Now it's your arena, override parent theme's templates, override parent theme's styles however you want. In one of my project, I added FontAwesome what was absent in parent theme, in this way:

In the above mentioned function I added a new line:

```
wp_enqueue_style( 'fontawesome-style', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/css/font-awesome.min.css' );
```

Note that, I'm using `get_stylesheet_directory_uri()`, because now we are using new resources that is where the overriding stylesheet is. So all you additional stylesheet can be enqueued in this way: