# Enqueue stylesheets if parent theme has more than one .css file

Tags: child-theme, wp-enqueue-style

I just learnt about creating child themes from [the Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes) , it says to add

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_enqueue_styles' );
function theme_enqueue_styles() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'parent-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );

}
```

and

```
function theme_enqueue_styles() {

    $parent_style = 'parent-style';

    wp_enqueue_style( $parent_style, get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'child-style',
        get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/style.css',
        array( $parent_style )
    );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_enqueue_styles' );
```

in my child theme's `functions.php` file but it did not address the issue when our parent theme has more then one style sheet(`.css files`). (In my case twenty-fourteen theme has two `style.css` and `rtl.css`) and two more in /css folder named `editor-style.css` and `ie.css` So what I have to change in the code above to load both `stylesheets`.

I have gone through [this question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/178381/enqueue-more-than-two-css-styles-in-a-child-theme-functions-php) but it did not address my issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Twenty fourteen loads its stylesheets differently in that it made the main stylesheet dependant on the genericon stylesheet, and I'm sure that this is the problem you are experiencing. (*if not, please update your question with proper details*)

You can change how you enqueue your style in the first block of code as follow

```
wp_enqueue_style( 'parent-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css', array( 'genericons' ) );
```

### EDIT

You have a misunderstanding about how certain stylesheets are loaded. The child theme loads all stylesheets from the parent except the parent stylesheet. That is how the system was build. Now, there are stylesheets that are not loaded by the theme, but by Wordpress by default

- [`editor-style.css`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_editor_style) get loaded automatically on the TinyMCE editor. Please see the codex for a full explanation
- `rtl.css` only gets loaded when the website is set to a rtl language. On ltr languages like English, the stylesheet is not loaded. This is also done by default by Wordpress. Just a note, why would you want to load your rtl stylesheet on a ltr site. It is a waste of resources for one
- `ie.css` The ie stylesheet is only loaded when the current browser is IE8 or older. That is the whole purpose of the ie stylesheet. IE8 and older does not support media queries, so other styles needs to be loaded on that browser.

The **only** code you need in your child functions.php is the following

```
function theme_enqueue_styles() {

    wp_enqueue_style( 'parent-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css', array( 'genericons' ) );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'child-style',
        get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/style.css',
        array( 'parent-style' )
    );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_enqueue_styles' );
```

Comment: actually all four (mentioned in the question) `stylesheets` are not being loaded by child theme by the code above.

Comment: this is my `functions.php` file [link](http://www.heypasteit.com/clip/227P)

Comment: You cannot use the same handle for all stylesheets, it will not work

Comment: Also, you cannot redeclare the same function name, you'll get a fatal error

Comment: I know it , please give me a solution instead :)

Comment: Are you getting the hang of this now?

Comment: I added the above code `add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_enqueue_styles' );
function theme_enqueue_styles() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'parent-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css', array( 'genericons' ) );

}` but website's old look collapsed :/ when I activated the child theme.

Comment: I will update, I think with this dependency of the parent style, the parent style is loading after child style :-)

Comment: Please see my update. Should work now

Comment: did not work :/

Comment: Well, it work perfect on my side. What the hell is *did not work*. Please give some context. I can do nothing with *did not work*. Clear your caches as well, browser and plugin

Comment: I tried the methods told by you but when I activate child theme my website's look is changed , so what I am supposed to do now ??

Comment: I suspect your stylesheet header is wrong. I can promise you, the code in my answer works. File an edit and add your stylesheet header in your question so I can have a look at it

Comment: this is my child theme [stylesheet] (http://www.heypasteit.com/clip/22KM) and my `child theme` is placed in `themes` directory.